# Function(index, value not presenting data?

Tags: javascript, json

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SMA&symbol=MSFT&interval=weekly&time_period=10&series_type=open&apikey=_______',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $(data.SMA).each(function(index, value){
                    console.log(value);
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
<html>
```

**Data**

[image]

I am trying to get the data to display the price, but when I feed the index, value it does not show the price displayed inside the data.

It does not show anything, what am I missing?

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use Google Dev Tools to debug your code. Start by pressing Ctrl-Shift-I.

Comment: I am, no code errors.

Comment: There may be no JavaScript errors, but since you do not get the expected output, there is a logic error. Using a debugger will help you find the error. Set a break point on the line `console.log(value)` and inspect the value of `data`, `index` and `value`.

Answer (score 0):

The `SMS` values are within this object `Technical Analysis: SMA`

```js
console.log('Retrieving data...');
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SMA&symbol=MSFT&interval=weekly&time_period=10&series_type=open&apikey=G8M336NY2UCXEZL7',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    var target = data['Technical Analysis: SMA'];
    $(Object.keys(target)).each(function(index, key) {
      console.log(target[key].SMA);
    });
    
    console.log('Done!');
  }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```